# "....has no exported member"-error in importing component (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, components

i am making a component called headerComponent and importing in app.component.ts but getting website/src/app/header/app.headerComponent"' has no exported member 'headerComponent' error my app.headerComponent.ts code is as follow

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'header',
 templateUrl: './app/header/header.html'
 })
 export class headerComponent {}
```

and app.component.ts code is as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 import { headerComponent } from './header/app.headerComponent';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent {
   }
```

Comment: Did you add it to your `@NgModule` ?

Comment: how to add in NgModule ??

Comment: Follow the tutorial from the official documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the component to your module.ts

```
import { headerComponent } from './header/app.headerComponent';
```

then,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [
    headerComponent 
  ]
```

Comment: import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { headerComponent } from './header/app.headerComponent';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, headerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, headerComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: there is already AppComponent should i add headerComponent with , in declarations ?

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Failed to compile.

C:/Users/anonymous/Desktop/website/src/app/app.component.ts (3,10): Module '"C:/Users/anonymous/Desktop/website/src/app/header/app.headerComponent"' has no exported member 'headerComponent'.

Comment: import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { headerComponent } from './header/app.headerComponent';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, headerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Answer (score 0):

Fixed similar error by updating the Typescript version